# Add styling to <div> content in ngx-editor

Tags: angular, ngx-editor

`"Image material<div><img src=\"data:image/webp;base64,UklGRvbHBABXRUJQVlA4IOrHBACQnhKdASqABzgEPkkgjkSioiEqJxGrwUAJCWVtfsPeD5/GZ/V6EP8nDf5pwbP4vVF0PlVs/6uT1A5t7fli/awETFU4E/E13+teWhz3+2eC/7f/6P855G/Tg47CKAag1P1VUpxdES/CG7Wms2taPD7TbtfknPLWiCWa6YAAAAA==\" style=\"letter-spacing: -0.1px;\"><br></div>"`

How can I add styling to the above `<div>` using ngx-editor: 4.1.0. I have found some solutions but they are only available for ngx-editor version 5 or higher. Unfortunately, my angular version does not support ngx-editor version 5 or higher?